# How to add modification history inside Oracle view

Tags: oracle10g, toad

I want to add the modification history inside an oracle view (at the top)

Below is an example:

```
/*Version   Modified-Date    Description*/
/*======================================*/
/*1.0       01/22/2013     Test view to generate current date and time*/
/*1.1       01/26/2013     Changed the date format*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MyView
AS
select * from mytable
```

When i try to run the above code in Toad editor it strips the comments and just creates the view. If i place the comments at the bottom then displays the modification history, but i it to display at the top.

I am using oracle 10g and Toad Data point

TIA

Answer (score 1):

if you mean to have it store in the view ddl then do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MyView
AS
select 
/*Version   Modified-Date    Description*/
/*======================================*/
/*1.0       01/22/2013     Test view to generate current date and time*/
/*1.1       01/26/2013     Changed the date format*/
* from mytable
```